# JMETER - MongoDB delete record sample script for jmeter

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

Can someone help me on groovy sample code for deleting a record from a MongoDB collection ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to removing an object your need to **find** one.

Full sample code (my expectation is that you're interested in the last line only, but just in case):

```
import com.mongodb.*  // import all the mongodb.* stuff
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;


DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("MongoDBSourceName", "DatabaseName");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("CollectionName");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name", "value"); // create DBObject holding the query
DBObject result = collection.findOne(query); // find the document

collection.remove(result); //delete the document
```

References:

- [DBCollection class JavaDoc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) (see [remove()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#remove-com.mongodb.DBObject-) and [findAndRemove()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndRemove-com.mongodb.DBObject-) methods in particular)
- [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It worked !!. Appreciate your quick response and help.